# Raspberry PiのGUIが起動しない

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Raspberry Pi 3 B+を使用しています。
OSはRaspbianで、2018年夏頃ダウンロードしたものです。

使い始めて5ヶ月くらいになりますが、最近まで正常に起動していました。
カメラモジュールで写真や動画の撮影をする用途で使用していましたが、
ある日、バッファが足りないというエラーが出てしまい、撮影ができなくなり、電源を落としました。
そして再度電源をつけたところ、GUIが起動しなくなりました。

電源をつけ、ラズベリーのマークが表示され、Welcome to RaspberryPiの画面は出るのですが、
そのあと黒い画面になり、左上にカーソルが点滅しているだけで、デスクトップ画面が起動しません。

Ctrl+Alt+F1でCUIを起動できますが、rebootしても同じ結果になります。

PowerのランプもActもどちらも点灯しているのでRaspberryPi本体ではなくSDカードが原因だと思います。
試しに、別のRaspberryPiで起動してみても同じ結果でした。

SDカードをフォーマットし直さなければいけないのでしょうか？

SDカードに入っている写真や動画のデータが消えていないか心配です…

宜しくお願いします……

Comment: CUIでのログイン、コマンドの実行等は出来ているのでしょうか。

Comment: 目的はbootしなくなったSDカードからのデータ取りだしだと思いますので、別のSDカードでRaspberryPiの起動環境（あるいはLinuxの入ったPCでもいいです）を作り、bootしなくなった方はカードリーダーなどでUSBで接続し、マウントできるか試すのがいいと思います。boot関係が壊れただけなら、これでファイルをコピーして取り出せると思います。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=227327&p=1394620

Comment: CUIを起動し、USBをマウントし写真や動画のデータをコピーしました。
元データを消去したところ、GUIが起動したので、やはりmicroSDカードのメモリ不足が原因だったようです。皆様ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コマンドは打てますか？
打てるなら「startx」と入力してください。

Comment: 上記のコメント欄に原因と解決結果を書きました、お返事いただきありがとうございました…！